# IIS Child application

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-8

Hosted Angular 2 project in IIS 8.5 server. And I want to use my Asp.net project in same port like child application. So, I have created an application under my angular website and pointed it to Asp.net application folder, I gave permissions too.
`http://localhost/api` (api is alias name for Asp.net project) but not able to accss `http://localhost/api/mycontroller/method`.

In Asp.net webconfig what are the changed I have to do?
Added `inheritInChildApplications` in config file,but no use
`<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
   <system.web>`

In angular web.config

```
<httpProtocol>

     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
     </customHeaders>

   </httpProtocol>
```

and in Asp.net webconfig

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"><system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization,*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

So am getting `Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` error.

Comment: Define "not able to access." 404? 403? 500? What do the logs say?

Comment: My bad, while doing debug itself I have posted my query in Stackoverflow. I have put inheritInChildApplications=false in Childapplication instead of parent